# Find Those Chews Notations! #6

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Here be a hearty return to the original point of this series: retrograde analysis!

Number Of Moves: 12

Checkmater: White

Given Game:

1. ? ?
2. ? ?
3. ? ?
4. ? 0-0
5. ? ?
6. ? ?
7. ? ?
8. Nf6+ Kh8
9. ? ?
10. ? ?
11. Nxf5 ?
12. Ng6#

Cryptic Clue #1: The black king dies a lonely death.

Cryptic Clue #2: No white queens or bishops are allowed.

Cryptic Clue #3: The white rook pawns do not move at all.

Cryptic Clue #4: (Optional): What words awoke the time traveler who came from the blue train?

Task: To use retrograde analysis and give an answer with all of the question marked moves solved, along with reasons for each move and all of the cryptic clues. A simple PGN post shall suffice. A link is optional.

Good luck, and go find those notations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the clue explicitly said:

Cryptic Clue #1: The black king dies a lonely death.

> He got cornered and died alone.

Cryptic Clue #2: No white queens or bishops are allowed.

> (No queen and bishop moves by white.

Cryptic Clue #3: The white rook pawns do not move at all.

> No rook pawn moves by white.

I think the following move set do the job:

> 1. d4 e5
>  2. dxe5 Bd6
>  3. exd6 Ne7
>  4. Nf3 **O-O**
>  5. Nc3 f5
>  6. Nd5 g5
>  7. dxe7 h5
>  8. **Nf6+ Kh8**
>  9. exf8=N g4
>  10. Nh4 Qe8
>  11. **Nxf5** Qe7
>  12. **Ng6#**

Given moves are bolded.

Comment: Adding to what @RewanDemontay said, this is the retrograde analysis! (The actual purpose of this comment was more to do with reminding myself of that xD)

Comment: Not sure what's more to explain. Since there is no bishop and queen to move the only possible way is using pawn and knight.